# How to set Main Activitie's Intent flag when it comes via Back press?

Tags: animation, android-intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Meet.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(i);
```

But when I press BackKey Main Activity is comes With normal Animation.

How can i Stop Main Activities Animation While it coming back From Stack.

I trried..

```
requestWindowFeature(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```

But not Working..

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in your activity in which you want to implement Back Press Event

```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
         SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("BackFlag", 0);
         SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
         ed.putString("Activity_Flag", "1");
         ed.commit();
         super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Now after it receives in the back activity,you can write this code after setContentView

```
     SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("BackFlag", 0);
     if(sp.getString("INSERT_FLAG", "").compareTo("1") == 0) 
     {
            //Code without animation
     }
     else 
     {
            //Code with which animation occurs
     }
```

i would suggest u make a seperate class for animation to make the code reUsable.